# Killing form explicitly

Tags: lie-algebras

Let's take the Killing form $B(X,Y):=Tr(ad(X)ad(Y))$. I would like to find the explicit form for some Lie algebras such as $su(n)$ or $gl(n)$ (further examples are given on Wikipedia). My question is now what the best way is to do that. An explicit calculation should be a straight-forward process I suppose. Are there other more economic ways to do it?

Comment: You might find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798995/killing-form-on-mathfraksp2n/1799014#1799014 interesting